# Yet another batch of four sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

This is my sixth batch of sequence puzzles that are nasty and hard to solve; 
yet, each of them has a clear and justifiable solution.

---

> Sequence 1:
>     Ca, Cl, ??, Er, ??, Po, Te, Th, ??

---

> Sequence 2:
>   A, G, ?, G, ?, W, V, E, G, E, ?, ?

---

> Sequence 3:
>   ..., 1906, 1912, 1918, 1936, 1938, ????, ????, 1978, ????, 1992, 1998, 2002, 2004, 2008, ...

---

> Sequence 4:
>   ?, ?, ?, R, A, O, T, E, L, A, I, D, L, N, A, S, Y, A, E, D, ...

Comment: is each of them a puzzle or are they combined?

Comment: Sequence 1 consist entirely from elements from the periodic table of elements. The numbers of the elements are 20, 17, ??, 68, ??, 84, 52, 90, ?? . However, I still cannot find the connection between those numbers. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as 4 separate puzzles? What if someone correctly answers Sequences 1 and 2, and another correctly answers Sequences 3 and 4. Who gets the credit then? Is it possible to place the green check mark on two answers?

Comment: Once again the prize goes to Len.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence 1 is a list of the:

> **[nine muses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muse)** of Greek mythology as follows (bold for missing letters):
>
>   Calliope, Clio, **Euterpe**, Erato, **Melpomene**, Polyhymnia, Terpsichore, Thalia, **Urania**

Sequence 2 is the order of the:

> **[British monarchs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_monarchs)** as follows (bold for missing letters):
>
>  Anne, George I, **George II**, George III, **George IV**, William IV, Victoria, Edward VII,  George V, Edward VIII, **George VI**, **Elizabeth II**

Sequence 4 is a list of the:

> **second letters of the abbreviation of US states** (bold for missing letters).
>   The order is alphabetical based on the full state name.
>
>  **AL, AK, AZ**, AR, CA, CO, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, ID, IL, IN, IA, KS, KY, LA, ME, MD...

Answer (score 4):

Sequence 3:

> looks like years, but actually is primes plus five.
>
>  The page http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt lists the first 10.000 
>  primes:
>  **..., 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, ...**
>  By adding 5 to each number, this list turns into
>  **..., 1906, 1912, 1918, 1936, 1938, 1954, 1956, 1978, 1984, 1992, 1998, 2002, 2004, 2008, ...**