# Find the 9th and final letter in the list

Tags: letter-sequence

There have been some recent letter-sequence puzzles that have been well-received. For example,

[Three different, and somewhat difficult, sequence puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/three-different-and-somewhat-difficult-sequence-puzzles)

[Two Bowls of Alphabet Soup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11348/two-bowls-of-alphabet-soup)

[Yet another batch of four sequence puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10298/yet-another-batch-of-four-sequence-puzzles)

So I thought I'd try to make one. I include only one puzzle here, instead of many, like other posts, so that it is obvious who to award the answer to.

---

There are 9 items in this list. The first 8 of them are represented by the letters below.

Find the last one.

### S N A X M P N I _

Hint:

> This list was published anonymously during the first 25 years of the 19th century, but 14 years later, someone claimed authorship.

Comment: I have never tried to make a puzzle of this type, but they seem to be some of the easiest puzzles to create, as nearly anything that can be listed qualifies. Nevertheless, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you don't like these types of puzzles, please move on to something that you enjoy. There is no need to downvote a puzzle just because you don't think it is interesting. In general, if there is something wrong with a puzzle, such as grammar, or it's not really a puzzle, then downvote, but if you do, always leave some constructive criticism so that the author can improve and learn.

Comment: Got it. It was easy :D

Comment: My instincts said to post it first, and then bring in the hint later. I should have went with my instincts. But you are still a puzzle-solving machine!

Comment: @JLee To the contrary, though JoeZ solved it amazingly fast, I think the puzzle greatly benefits from the hint. It gives something to ponder rather that just starting at the letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **D**.

> "Now, Da**s**her! Now, Da**n**cer! Now, Pr**a**ncer, and Vi**x**en!
>  On, Co**m**et! On, Cu**p**id! On, Du**n**der and Bl**i**xem!"
>
>  The above two lines are from *A Visit from St. Nicholas*, which was published in 1823, and later claimed to be authored by Clement Clarke Moore in 1837, fourteen years later.
>
>  The letters in the sequence are the third letters of the names of Santa's eight reindeer.
>  The reindeer's names haven't changed much since then; Dunder became Donner and Blixem became Blitzen, but their third letters are still identical.
>
>  The next one would be the ninth reindeer introduced in the 1949 Christmas carol that changed Dunder and Blixem's names in the first place, *Ru**d**olph the Red-Nosed Reindeer*.

Comment: Would you have got it that quickly without the hint? I am guessing yes.

Comment: I am impressed! How on earth did you solve this so fast?

Comment: The hint helped. I was thinking about collections of things that had eight elements with a ninth one tacked on. The planets were my first thought, and then suddenly I thought of *The Night Before Christmas* and then Santa's reindeer when I noticed the clue that it was a publication from the 19th century.